# How setuptools deals with transitive dependencies?

Tags: python, setuptools

Let's say I have a setuptools project that depends on

- PyPi package A, v. 1.0.
- PyPi package B, v. 1.0.

and package B depends on A, v. 2.0.

In Java I would have to exclude transitive dependencies in `pom.xml` or similar. How does it work in setuptools? Can multiple versions of the same package live together in an installation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This won't work with setuptools; you cannot override dependencies like that, for good reasons.

What you describe is a broken dependency; you'll have to resolve this manually (probably by pinning package A to v. 2.0).

Comment: Because if a package is firm about a version pin, overriding that will break things, guaranteed. You may as well fork the package, update it's requirements and *fix the issues that emerge* in the fork.